# Installation issue in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-10.04, apt, ufw

i wanted to install ufw in my ubuntu 10.04. but, when i try to instal ufw the apt-get installer stalls my progress by trying too install my-sql server, which i dont want to install right now.

Is there any way in which i can bypass the mysql installation and just install ufw...installing my-sql gives me a fear of rendering my applications corrupt, hence i dont want to go forward with it.

[image: Screenshot of the process]

Comment: You already installed `mysql-server-5.1` previously, `apt-get` just wants to update it. So your question makes little sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL upgrades rarely cause data corruption (it has *never* happened to me) but even that shouldn't be a cause for worry if you have backups of your data and a tested backup procedure.

You *do* have tested backups don't you?

If you're still worried about it, try running the upgrade on a test system with the same data and MySQL being upgraded from the same version.

Or better yet, set up a redundant pair of database servers and upgrade one, fail over to it then upgrade the other.

Comment: i know my system already has mysql on it, but whenever i try to upgrade it, it just stops at my-sql server and doesnt move ahead for a lot of time.....and the system i m trying to upgrade is, is very critical...so that is why, i didnt want any data corruption, hence asked for a way to avoid the my-sql from being upgraded